# Applying function to each group and column of R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I need to apply this function

```
replace_outliers <- function(column) {
  qnt <- quantile(column, probs=c(.25, .75))
  upper_whisker <- 1.5 * IQR(column)
  clean_data <- column
  clean_data[column > (qnt[2] + upper_whisker)] <- median(column)
  clean_data
}
```

to dataset that look like this:

```
  Category       a       b       c
       a       2.0     5.0    -5.0
       a       1.5    10.0    10.0
       b       3.2    14.5   100.2
     ...       ...     ...     ...
```

I have to apply `replace_outliers` to each category apart and for each column. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package `dplyr`. Use `group_by` to do it for each Category and `mutate_if` to apply the function to all numerical columns

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
                   " Category       a       b       c
       a       2.0     5.0    -5.0
                 a       1.5    10.0    10.0
                 b       3.2    14.5   100.2")
replace_outliers <- function(column) {
  qnt <- quantile(column, probs=c(.25, .75))
  upper_whisker <- 1.5 * IQR(column)
  clean_data <- column
  clean_data[column > (qnt[2] + upper_whisker)] <- median(column)
  clean_data
}

df %>% group_by(Category) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_outliers)
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I have numeric columns on which I don't want to apply this function?

Comment: You could look into `mutate_at` which you can give a list of variable names or indexes

Answer (score 2):

Use `mutate_all` within a `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate_all(replace_outliers) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider `base R` with `by` (to split by *category*), `sapply` (to call function), and `do.call` to bind all groups back together:

```
df_list <- by(data, data$category, function(sub) {
  sub[-1] <- sapply(sub[-1], replace_outliers)
  sub
})

final_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list))
```